# SQL - Select records only with inactive status

Tags: sql, oracle, ansi-sql, netezza

I have following requirement.

```
**---Table A---**
CustID_1   S1    
CustID_1   S2    
CustID_2   S2    
CustID_2   S3    
CustID_3   S4 
CustID_3   S5


**---Table B---**
S1     1
S2     0
S3     1
S4     0
S5     0
```

I want to select all CustID's where all B.S = 0.
So in above case only CustID_3 should be selected. CustID_1, CustID_2 are having atleast a S=1 so they should not appear in result.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: Homework? What did you write so far?

Comment: I am not a SQL guy. thats why seeking some help.

Comment: +1 for providing samples of your input data from both tables and describing your desired output. -1 for not bothering to provide column names or what you've tried so far that isn't working for you. All in all, you break even. Maybe next question you'll provide everything and get an actual + vote. :)

Comment: Thanks Ken. will take care next time. btw...@SQLMenace = Manic

Answer (score 1):

Untested:

```
SELECT custid
  FROM A a1 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
       (SELECT custid
          FROM A a2 JOIN B ON (a2.col2 = B.col1)
         WHERE B.col2 = 1
           AND a2.custid = a1.custid)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one; it returns all the custIDs that are not present in B **and** those for which B.S' value equals 0:

```
SELECT
    A.custID
FROM
    A
WHERE
    A.custID NOT IN
    (
        SELECT
            B.custID
        WHERE
            B.S <> 0
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.CustID
FROM TableA a
  INNER JOIN TableB b ON a.S = b.S
GROUP BY a.CustID
HAVING SUM(b.S) = 0
```